# node elasticsearch client causing memory leak

Tags: node.js, express, memory-leaks, elasticsearch

In my web application I am using node elasticsearch client.
with rest client I am testing the application.
I sent a request with postman test runner with number of iteration 1000 and observed memory is increase.

Before running any test case app is taking 45MB~.
After running test case with 1000 iterations app is consuming ~90MB.
After re running the same test case memory is growing to ~120MB.
I feel there is a memory leak in the application.

Node version: 0.12.5
Elasticsearch DB version: 1.5.2
Elasticsearch node client: 4.0.2

Sample code:

```
var client = new elasticsearch.Client({
  hosts: elasticHosts
});


app.all('*', function(req, res, next) {
  validateApiKey(req.headers["apikey"],next,res);    
})

function validateApiKey(ApiKey,next,response) {
    var hits;
    var isValidApiKey = false

    client.search({
      index: 'clients',
      type: 'search',
      body: {
        "query":{
        "match":{
          "apikey" : ApiKey                  
        }
      }
    }
  },function(err,res) {
  response.send(true);
}
```

I noticed memory leak happening if use node version 0.10.39.

Is it a problem with node version? or Elasticsearch client version? or with my code?

Can some helps to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

To eyeball if there is even an indication of a memory leak, use process.memoryUsage()
https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_memoryusage

The output will be in the following format:

```
{ rss: 4935680,
  heapTotal: 1826816,
  heapUsed: 650472 }
```

It seems like normal behaviour for the rss (resident set size) to grow consistently if you are buffering up a lot of data (likely the case with Elasticsearch). Therefore the heapTotal and heapUsed metrics are more likely to be better indicators.

If your had app is not hanging or suffering degraded performance over time, it may not indicate a memory leak.

Take a look at http://jayconrod.com/posts/55/a-tour-of-v8-garbage-collection for a bit more of an in depth look at v8 garbage collection.

If you still suspect a memory leak, or your app is showing the telltale signs listed above, you may want to look into tracking the leak with something such as https://www.npmjs.com/package/memwatch

Comment: Hi snozza , Thanks for the suggestion.  For each rest api call, I observed memory is increasing. with postman rest client I ran 3K times same query, memory is keep on increasing. I noticed memory increase with the help of pm2 and linux command ps. Do you feel is there any bug in the code causing this issue? Does elasticsearch node client cache data in application? If it is the case how can I clear this cache in the application.

Comment: It is hard to tell without knowing specifics of the app what may cause the memory leak (assuming there is one). I found this guide very handy http://www.nearform.com/nodecrunch/self-detect-memory-leak-node/  It should help you track down what is causing the memory increase. You will probably find more success analysing your app directly.

Comment: I used memwatch listeners, it is not giving any memory leaks. But still memory is keep increasing. just because of the above code memory is increasing, you can easily reproduce memleak with the above code. snozza can suggest a way to overcome this issue.